# Load Excel 2007 file with columns more than IV into SQL Server table using SQL Server Import Export Wizard

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have an Excel `.xlsx` file that has data columns extending to the `NZ` column (total 390 columns). Each column has data specific to that column. I want to load these data into a SQL Server table.

I tried to use the SQL Import Export wizard for loading this Excel file into the SQL Server table. However the Excel is not loaded fully. The data is only loaded up to the `IV` column. The columns after `IV` (to `NZ`) are not getting loaded into the table.

The Excel is 64 bit version and I have installed Access Database Engine 2010 64 bit as well as Access database Engine 2007 32 bit version in my system.

I googled and found in some forums they have mentioned that these much of columns can be loaded only using Flat Files.

Is there any way to load the excel with more than 300 columns into a SQL Server table without changing to a flat file?

Comment: I have never tried this, however, I flat files refer to files used for bulk insert or excel converted to csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose Excel 97-2003 as Excel version, the maximum number of columns is 256. If you have the option in the data source dialog of the Import/Export Wizard to choose Excel 2007 as the Excel version, select that, and you should be able to import up to 16,000 columns.  Of course, if you convert your file to a CSV or a TXT format, you can easily get around that 256 column limitation.